# Отображение label (tableViewCell) вне ячейки

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Возможно ли отобразить лейбл из **tableViewCell** вне ячейки? Т.е. стандартно лейбл отображается в методе

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! DetailTableViewCell2

    cell2.currentPageNumber.text = "1/\(Images?.Photo.count ?? 0)"

return cell2
```

А мне нужно отобразить **currentPageNumber.text** в этом методе

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
```

И сама ячейка:

```
class DetailTableViewCell2: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var currentPageNumber: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        currentPageNumber.layer.zPosition = 2
        currentPageNumber.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        currentPageNumber.clipsToBounds = true

    }

}
```

Возможно ли это сделать? И если возможно то как?

Comment: не совсем понимаю в чем именно проблема, что мешает выставить currentPageNumber.text через indexPath ячейки ?. Что означает "вне ячейки но внутри tableViewController" если просто лейбл должен просто висеть то всегда можно прикрутить его над tableView и менять в зависимости от текущего элемента, а иначе лейбл будет скроллится вместе с ячейкой

Comment: как его выставить через indexPath в метод func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) ?
"вне ячейки но внутри tableViewController" насчет этого глупость написал, исправил вопрос))

Comment: а зачем вам его там менять он будет стерпится вместе с загрузкой ячейки в func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) , например 10 ячеек -> 10 лейблов с номером

Comment: Я хочу отображать текущую ячейку на котором будет находится пользователь и общее количество ячеек, т.е. 5/10 или 6/10 и тд. Я в этом методе 
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)  
уже делал на обычном scrollView, но теперь мне надо это сделать в ячейке колекции

Comment: ну я тогда правильно представляю, есть таблица с ячейками а допустим внизу висит лейбл в котором мне показывает например 3/10 и лейбл не скроллится вместе с ячейкой ?

Comment: Да, лейбл не скролится вместе, просто висит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну можно вот так сделать

вью контроллер:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var viewLabel: UILabel!
    private let numberOfRows = 10

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.viewLabel.text = "1/\(self.numberOfRows)"
        self.tableView.rowHeight = self.tableView.frame.height //для отображения ячейки на весь екран
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.tableView.delegate = nil
        self.tableView.dataSource = nil
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.numberOfRows
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseCell")
        // настраиваем селу
        return cell!
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.changeLabel((self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last?[1] ?? 0) + 1) // берем последний елемент из видимых и получаем его номер, + 1 потому что первый - 0
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        // аналогично предыдущему методу
        self.changeLabel((self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?.last?[1] ?? 0) + 1)
    }

    private final func changeLabel(_ cellNumber: Int) {
        self.viewLabel.text = "\(cellNumber)/\(self.numberOfRows)"
    }

}
```

---

Сториборд :

[image: сториборд]

Comment: вариант тестовый настроите как вам нравится

Comment: Да это сработало, спасибо)) Моя ошибка наварно что я раньше это не написал, но у меня внутри тейблвью - колекшн вью и может можно как то приравнять этот лейбл чтобы он висел на уровне колекшнвью постоянно? Просто в колешкнвью стоит динамечесий размер элементов и колешкнвью может меняться в размере